# how can I retrieve values from NSMutableArray having object with multiple values

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSMutablearray` that has say 4 objects, and each object has further elements in it, I Want to retrieve those elements i.e.

Object at index 0 has 15 values( Ns strings) same is for rest of the 3 objects

I don't know the syntax of how can I read the values below syntax I have tried gives me error:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<[array count] ; i++) {
    for (int j=0 ; j<[array[i] count] ; j++) {
        /// reading code here
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ...and what code is REALLY where you put //// reading code here? That's where I suspect the error is.

Comment: When the program pointer reaches at the nested for loop line, i.e. which has array[i] count it gives error unrecognized selector sent (NS invalid argument exception)
is this syntax correct ?

Comment: there for now i am just print in NS log values of each object i Put a break point  at the second line and i get an error when i move forward in debugging

Comment: reading code here = NSlog (@"%@", array[i][j]);

Comment: Fast enumeration `for NSArray *subArray in array` has been introduced in Leopard (2007)

Comment: @vadian can you please give a syntax so that i can try then, not if this way i have to read all the values in the subarray

Answer (score 1):

Very simple example with two inner arrays containing three items respectively and Fast Enumeration:

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@"1", @"2", @"3"], @[@"4", @"5", @"6"]];
for (NSArray *subArray in array) {
  for (NSString *item in subArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
  }
}
```